# the first IP of the next block with Net::IP

Tags: perl, network-programming

i am trying to use Net::IP module from cpan

```
my $block = new Net::IP('194.158.1.0/24');
$block->ip() # get the first ip on the block
$block->last_ip() #get the last ip on the block
```

how can i increment the last ip , as i want to know the first ip on the next block

i tried something like :

```
++$block->last_ip()
```

but this is not working any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can't increment the last ip as mentioned in [Net::IP document](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IP#looping).

> The ++ operator returns undef when the last address of the range is reached.

The most simple way is to convert the last ip into integer, increment, then create a brand new Net::IP object from it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::IP qw(ip_inttobin ip_bintoip);

my $block = Net::IP->new('194.158.1.0/24');
my $next_bin = ip_inttobin($block->last_int + 1, $block->version);
my $next = Net::IP->new(ip_bintoip($next_bin, $block->version));
print $next->ip;
```